# Changing Google profile pictures lead to HTTP 400 errors on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, profile-page, avatar

When you go to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10068267/%E5%8F%B6%E8%BE%B0%E5%93%B2), you will see it won't load the avatar image. It doesn't look nice.

The avatar image links to https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-WhOGXqMqiFI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAnnY7ojmWfZhHg20Uah9gJOxMzEFvu_Jg/mo/photo.jpg?sz=256.

But it says error code 400.

Please note that this link was not entered by the user in the settings. It is possible to enter a link in the settings, but it will copy the image to [Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) first. So this URL was definitely not entered by the user.

From the comments, I've read it seems the user is registered using Google and changed his Google profile image (or Google changed the URL).

Comment: This looks like an issue with the URL. What is SO supposed to do about it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi SO creates these links. So they should be able to fix it.

Comment: They do? This looks like a "link from the web" profile image provided by the user.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi There is no option to use a "link from the web" as avatar image in the settings. So this link must come from SO?

Comment: @zomega You can specify your image by [editing your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current). Also that image is coming from the specific user's account they probably changed their profile picture on Google and possibly deleted the old one. Not really a bug on Stack Overflow's side since it just picked their profile picture URL from Google on their account creation.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Shouldn't SO update the picture URL if someone logs in to SO using his Google account and changes his profile picture on Google?

Comment: Also what you're saying it's possible to use a link as image in the settings I cannot confirm this. https://imgur.com/a/rYjGeZB

Comment: @zomega Why particularly? That just opens up more issues. You can have multiple  logins associated with your account. What happens then? Which one should Stack Overflow decide to use? Also people might then complain about Stack Overflow changing the image when they didn't want to. The simplest approach is to let the user decide on when (and if) they want to update the image.

Comment: IIRC those urls are provided by Google when someone creates an account using a Google account, and the image URL returned by Google break semi-frequently, frequently enough that they've broken in the past. I'd argue not an SO problem

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat SO could copy over the image from Google to SO upon registration for example.

Comment: @zomega they likely could _not_ do that, as the images are likely licensed to Google (and only Google) when set up on the Google account

Comment: @zomega "Also what you're saying it's possible to use a link as image in the settings I cannot confirm this. imgur.com/a/rYjGeZB" in that menu click on "uploaded picture" which gives the option to newly upload one or to "link from the web".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried out this function. It will copy the image to imgur. So what you said that sometimes people enter URLs there which are later down is simply not true.

Comment: @zomega Okay on the "this wasn't provided that way" and thanks for checking. But then we agree that the URLs created by SO aren't like that either way, don't we? Because if it were it would point to imgur.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes I agree. It seems this happens if you register to SO using a Google account. Later if you change the Google profile picture (or Google changes URL locations) this error happens.

Answer (score 14):

There have been issues with the Google provided avatar images:

- [My picture is missing on my profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322761/my-picture-is-missing-on-my-profile-page)
- [What can we do with broken avatars generated by Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322759/what-can-we-do-with-broken-avatars-generated-by-google)
- [Invalid size parameters break avatars served by Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355948/invalid-size-parameters-break-avatars-served-by-google)

but in the end the user controls whether that initial image URL that was given to SE when they signed up remains valid. When the user changes their Google profile image, there is nothing SE can do. The user is in control over their avatar. If they want ensure that image doesn't change, they have to upload an image to SE and use that going forward.

The profile image for that user is gone at the Google site and there is nothing we can do about it. The user has to fix that, if they want to.

Comment: "When the user changes their Google profile image, there is nothing SE can do." Is that so? If SO could query the original URL, shouldn't they be able to get the updated URL as well?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm not sure. Did we grant SE that permission to read our Google profile after we signed up? Still, that is an FR, not a bug.